# Flask - getting value from radio button? werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request

Tags: html, flask, radio-button, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to get the value of a radio button and getting a BadRequestKeyError: 400 whenever I try to access "http://127.0.0.1:5000/submissions"

The error code description is: werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'submission'

Here is the relevant code (feel free to ignore `print(selected_song)` after `selected_song = requests.form["submission"]`)

Flask:

```
@app.route("/submissions", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def submissions():
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=current_user.email).first_or_404()
    if user.user_type == "Artist":
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        submissions = Upload.query.filter_by(artist=current_user)\
            .order_by(Upload.date_submission.desc())\
            .paginate(page=page, per_page=5)        
        selected_song = request.form["submission"]
        print(selected_song)
        return render_template('submissions.html', submissions=submissions, title='Submit')
    else:
        return render_template('submissions.html')
```

HTML:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %} 
{% block content %}
    {% if submissions %}
      </div>
        {% for submission in submissions.items %}
          <form action="" method="POST">
            <article class="media content-section">
              <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pictures/' + submission.artist.image_file) }}">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2" href="{{ url_for('user_submissions', username=submission.artist.username) }}">{{ submission.artist.username }}</a>
                  <small class="text-muted">{{ submission.date_submission.strftime('%B %d, %Y') }}</small>
                </div>
                <input type="radio" name="submission" value="{{submission.id}}"><a target="_blank"></a><a class="article-title" href="{{ url_for('submission', submission_id=submission.id)  }}"> {{ submission.artists_from_song }} - {{ submission.song_name }}</a>
                <a href="{{ submission.song_link }}"><iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/{{submission.song_uri}}" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe></a>
                <p class="article-content">Song Description: {{ submission.song_description }}</p>
              </div>
            </article>
            <input type=submit value="Submit Your Song">
          </form>
        {% endfor %}
      {% for page_num in submissions.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
        {% if page_num %}
          {% if submissions.page == page_num %}
            <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('submissions', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }} </a>
          {% else %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('submissions', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }} </a>
          {% endif %}
        {% else %}
        ...
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        <div>
            <p class="text-center text-muted">You're not logged in with an artist account<p>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not have an if statement to check if the form was submitted or if the page is being loaded the first time.

Keeping the HTML the same, the Python code should be updated as follows:

```
@app.route("/submissions", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def submissions():
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=current_user.email).first_or_404()
    if user.user_type == "Artist":
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        submissions = Upload.query.filter_by(artist=current_user)\
            .order_by(Upload.date_submission.desc())\
            .paginate(page=page, per_page=5)    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            selected_song = request.form["submission"]
            print(selected_song)
        return render_template('submissions.html', submissions=submissions, title='Submit')
    else:
        return render_template('submissions.html')
```